# What resource folder is picked first and what last?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I've got some weird bug and I have to deep inspect my layout and drawable structure, step by step, folder by folder. I tried to find a document which describes how Android opens some drawable or pulls some layout in terms of which folder is accessed first and which last - in steps from A to Z.

Can someone direct me to such document or (if such doc does not exist) describe me these steps here?

What I mean? Like we have Activity life-cycle doc which says which method is called first and which last, I need a doc which will say something like this `if the screen is Large Mdpi, then system will first look into X layout directory, then into Y and last into Z layout directory. If a screen is Large Mdpi, then the system will first pull a drawable from XX dir, then YY dir and lastly from ZZ dir`. Something like this.

Comment: So I am still looking for some doc or web document which analyzes which folder it picked first, which one is next, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right which explains everything. It's made by Google Android team.

[>> The link <<](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)

(`http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch`)

Answer (score 1):

First it checks in the drawable folder based on the device density, lets say the device is hdpi, then it tries to pick up the image from drawable-hdpi folder if present, else it will look in to drawable folder and scale it accordingly, since drawable is generally considered as mdpi.  This is just an example of lot of variations available. for more info, look at this link.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: this link says nothing about the flaw. For example, in case I have `layout-sw600dp` and `layout-w600dp`, which one will be accessed first?

Answer (score 1):

**First resource:**
1) Best suitable resource folder picked up by android depending upon device on which is running.

2) Best folder depends upon folder you have provided for application, like app running on tablet it will pick up xlarge if not provided, then it will search for large res folder. and so on.

**Last resource:** In last it will look for default folder without any identifier